# Нужно ли очищать память в структуре sockaddr_in перед использованием?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Я видел множество примеров кода на C и C++, в некоторых используется такая конструкция:

```
sockaddr_in address;
ZeroMemory(&address, sizeof(address));
...
```

Для чего это сделано и в каких условиях должно быть применено?

Comment: Ответы можете почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15608707/3240681).

Answer (score 2):

Шон Уолтон в книге "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux", на стр 34 поясняет этот вопрос следующим образом:

В конце структуры sockaddr_in находится поле заполнителя, длина которого зависит от длины предшествующего адреса. Поскольку в ip4 и ip6 поле адреса имеет разную длину, то и заполнитель получается разной. длины.  Однако, в некоторых *NIX системах эти байты заполнителя используются для передачи некоторой дополнительной  информации.  Для того, что бы избежать конфликтов при передаче данных, принято эти поля заполнять нулями.